# Retrieving UTC timestamptzs from postgres in the correct time zone

Tags: postgresql, time

I store timestamps with time zone in my postgres database. The server time zone is UTC. All the timestamptzs are stored as UTC datetimes.

Now, I'd like to retrieve those timestamps, but for a specific time zone (e.g. US/Pacific). Because of daylight savings time, the correct time zone is sometimes PDT and sometimes PST. So I can't just run a query like `select t at time zone 'pdt'` because this will be wrong for the `pst` dates.

Is there a way to pull the dates from the database in the correct time zone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [**documentation**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html), together with `TIME ZONE` code you can also specify locales. For your case you can use something like that:

```
ds=# SELECT current_setting('TIMEZONE');
 current_setting 
-----------------
 UTC
(1 row)

ds=# SELECT now();
              now              
-------------------------------
 2015-11-05 00:35:03.126317+00
(1 row)

pm7=# SELECT now() AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles';
          timezone          
----------------------------
 2015-11-04 16:35:06.344367
(1 row)
```

Comment: Ah-ha. I didn't realize I could use `America/Los_Angeles`! I'll test this out. Thanks.